# javascript function within an object is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const md = {
  methodOne: () => {
    console.log(this.anotherMethod())
  },
  anotherMethod: () => 'anotherMethod'
}
```

When I do `md.methodOne()` I got `anotherMethod` is undefined error. How do I call `anotherMethod` in `methodOne`?

Comment: Arrow functions do not set `this`, so `this.anotherMethod` cannot be resolved. If you define `methodOne` with a `function` declaration, the code will work.

Comment: makes no sense to `console.log(this.anotherMethod())` since anotherMethod does not return anything

Comment: @epascarello edited my question, how about now? this is `gone` if I use arrow function, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your arrow functions.
An arrow function does not have its own `this`; the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context is used i.e. Arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not present in current scope they end up finding `this` from its enclosing scope . Thus, in the following code, the `this` within the function that is passed to setInterval has the same value as `this` in the lexically enclosing function:

Also,
you don't need to type `return` when you have :

```
() => return 'some message'
```

The arrow function will return implicitly the value or the result of an expression:

```
const msg =  () => 'some message'

const result = () => 5 * 5; //25
```

Just for the sake of it, this is how it should look:

```
const md = {
  methodOne:function () {
    console.log(this.anotherMethod());
  },
  anotherMethod: function (){
    return 'anotherMethod';
  }
}

console.log(md.methodOne());
```